# Does ZendStudio has included apache?

Tags: php, apache, zend-studio

I have installed the ZendStudio for developing PHP, I wonder need I to install apache?

Comment: AFAIR, old versions of Zend Studio featured/conatined webserver functionality, I do not remember which version :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend Studio does not come bundled with a webserver, but you can very much use any webserver you like with Zend Studio, including but not limited to Apache, nginx, lighttpd or even PHP 5.4's own built-in webserver. However, unless you are using [Zend Server](http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/features#serverint) for a webserver, integration will be limited.

Note that you only need a locally installed webserver when you want to serve webpages from your local machine. Zend Studio has various system connectors, so you can also work with remote servers or virtual machines. It's usually better to have the webserver running in a dev environment that is similar to the production site to prevent system setup conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

Yes definitely, as Zend Studio is just an [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) while apache is a [web server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server). Both are totally different things.